# Facebook Graph API: Getting a random N friends?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm unsure if this is possible --

I'm developing an Android game, and I want it to include profile pictures of 15 random friends.

However, it seems my only option is to call the graph API "/me/friends" (several times, with paging) to get *all* of a users friends, store the list, then randomly select a subset of friends and retrieve their profile photos.

I was wondering if there's a single call to the Graph API to sort randomly, or somehow reduce the footprint of this job, so that I can use their server-side `?limit=15` to reduce the requests my app has to make.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested to know the answer to this question, my question is the same, just not via android!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is possible via FQL query which you can run with Graph API

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (
  SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
) ORDER BY rand() limit 15
```

To get it via Graph API you just need to issue GET request to:

```
GET http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={QUERY_HERE}
```

Answer (score 0):

If not rand() , you can also use **offset** and **limit**

select uid2 from friend where uid1=me() limit 15 offset 15

This will make friend chosen the previous time, not appear again in the new 15 set of friends chosen the next time. I agree its not truly random, because when they say random, there are chances of the previous friends reappearing.