# Randomize/Shuffle array, then foreach, then limit to 10 results (Facebook API + PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, foreach

What I have here is a PHP page working with the Facebook API.

What I'm trying to do is (after permissions are set by the user), to get the user's friends' user IDs via: `$facebook->api('/me/friends')`. The problem is, I would only like to get **random 10 friends**. I could easily limit results to 10 by using `/me/friends?limit=10`, but then again that wouldn't be random.

So here is what I have right now:

```
     $friendsLists = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

     function getFriends($friendsLists){
       foreach ($friendsLists as $friends) {
          foreach ($friends as $friend) {
             // do something with the friend, but you only have id and name
             $id = $friend['id'];
             $name = $friend['name'];
        shuffle($id);
     return "@[".$id.":0],";
          }
       }
     }

$friendsies = getFriends($friendsLists);
$message = 'I found this Cover at <3 '.$Link.'

'.$friendsies.' check it out! :)';
```

I have tried shuffle(), and the first option from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1656983/1399030, but I think I could be doing something wrong because they don't return anything. I'm pretty sure I'm close, but what I've tried so far is not working. Can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API: Getting a random N friends?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570459/facebook-graph-api-getting-a-random-n-friends)

Comment: @EvanMulawski hopefully without the use of FQL queries. Since I already have the friendslist array, I would just need to know a way to shuffle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll want to use the shuffle before you foreach, so that you actually shuffle the array.

after that, you'll want to limit to 10 friends. I'd suggest adding an $i var to count to ten, and adding to a new array.

Something like this:

```
function getFriends($friendsLists){
   $formatted_friends = array();
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($friendsLists as $friends) {
      // I'm guessing we'll need to shuffle here, but might also be before the previous foreach
      shuffle($friends);
      foreach ($friends as $friend) {
         // do something with the friend, but you only have id and name
         // add friend as one of the ten
         $formatted_friends[$i] = $friend;
         // keep track of the count
         $i++;
         // once we hit 10 friends, return the result in an array
         if ($i == 10){ return $formatted_friends; }
      }
   }
 }
```

keep in mind though that it'll return an array and not a string that you can use in an echo. If you want, you can put this in an echo for debugging purposes:

```
echo 'friends: '.print_r($friendsies, true);
```

Comment: Thank you @Greg! I was only hoping to get the IDs though, like I how I have it on my current code that it separates the names and IDs, and then I'm able to use the IDs from there

Comment: Hello Greg, tried your code with another function like the one I originally had, just so I could break down the results of your code to just getting the IDs after it has been shuffled. So I ran it through another foreach function, but that's not working too well for me. I returns the word "Array", but I thought running it through my original function that it would break that array down, apparently I'm more ignorant that I think.

Comment: change this part to get just the id:
$formatted_friends[$i] = $friend;
to:
$formatted_friends[$i] = $friend['id'];. The word Array appears when you try to echo something that is an array. If you use PHP on strict mode, it'll also throw a warning (as arrays can't just be echoed). If you still want to echo, you can use the print_r() like I showed you, or for a more advanced format you could try an implode($friendsies, ',') to get a comma separated result. I guess though that if you're using the friend ids for some other function, you probably want to keep it an array.

Comment: Hi again Greg, thanks a lot, this is exactly the direction I'm wanting to go! But keeping it an array isn't necessarily what I need, as long as I can get the 10 random IDs in a foreach & format them the way I want (appending characters before & after each ID). As u can see from my previous code, I *foreached* the array, & made it display with `@[` before each ID, and `:0],` right after. The other function I was talking about was just another foreach function, so I could display each resulting ID the way I wanted. Now I foreached your results, but on my foreach it only returns 1 item. Lost here

Comment: I am really really almost there thanks to you and YOUR help, I'm hoping you could take me all the way through. I used this function to *foreach* the results from YOUR function: `function forIch($friendsies){
foreach ($friendsies as $key => $value) {
return "@[".$value.":0],";
 }
}`, but it is only returning 1 item. Though upon testing (using *print_r* of your results) I know that YOUR results are returning 10 items in an array correctly, so I'm thinking it's my foreach that ruins everything. I don't understand why it would return only 1 item.

Comment: I finally got it! This might actually be a really stupid way to do this, but I get what I want from it. :) Along w/ your code, I use: `$friendsies = getFriends($friendsLists);
$friendsies2 = implode($friendsies, ' ');
$friendsFinal = explode(" ", $friendsies2);` and echo results (appending the characters `@[` before each ID, and `:0],` after) by: `echo '@['.$friendsFinal[0].':0], @['.$friendsFinal[1].':0], @['.$friendsFinal[2].':0], @['.$friendsFinal[3].':0]';`... and this actually goes on til `$friendsFinal[9]` . Thanks again! If there's a smarter more sensible way to do this though? I'm open